# Determining object equivalence for value types, reference types and ILists in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, equivalence

I have a class with a Property called 'Value' which is of type Object.
Value can be of any type, a structure, a class, an array, IList etc.

My problem is with the setter and determining whether the value has changed or not.
This is simple enough for value types, but reference types and lists present a problem.

For a class, would you assume that the Equals method has been implemented correctly, or just assume that the value has changed every time the setter is called?
If I did assume it's changed, then perhaps I should assume it for value types as well, so that the behaviour is consistent.

For a list, I could check the size and then every item in the collection to see if they have changed.

How do you guys handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why should you care whether the value has changed or not? Is there a reason why you can't just  assume the value changed every time the setter is called?

If there is a good technical reason why, you could always use generics and make your `Value` of type [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) instead of type `object`. This ensures that the object has implemented the `Equals()` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both answers regarding IEquatable<T>, though I don't want to place this restriction on Value. The only reason I care about if the value has changed is because a ValueChanged event is raised. To be honest, I don't really care at all, so I'll just assume it's changed every time the setter is called!

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense, however I wouldn't go so far as to check the value of your property every time the setter is called. You'd suffer both in terms of performance and understandability. I think most programmers would expect the "`ValueChanged`" event to happen every time Value is set, not just when it is set with a new value.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having

```
object Value
```

you could declare

```
IEquatable<T> Value
```

This way you know that all instances of Value will implement the Equals method. Thus you can check equality of two instances.